# My jQuery scripts seem to be loading, but aren't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've spent three days trying to get my jQuery scripts to work on my wordpress theme, but I haven't had any luck with any of the tutorials I've found online.

I've managed to get to the stage where the scripts appear to be loading, but they aren't actually functioning. They are visible in the page source viewer, and when I click the link it comes up with the right code.

In my functions.php I have the following:

```
function lucieaverillphotography_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lucieaverillphotography scripts' );
```

My jQuery code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {

jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
});

});

});
```

I tried changing the jQuery to something more simple, but nothing seems to work.

This is a self built theme, so I could be missing something really simple that's causing everything I try to fail – does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

My website url is http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is problemu with your code, I made this screenshot using console with site on the tab.

[image: console.log]

jQuery can't find any `.nav-menu` element to add `.slideToggle()` effect on it. Just check all DOM classes are valid in HTML and Javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice – I think you could be right, but while I was making changes to the javascript file, something has happened to the function I've added and I'm now getting this error message above my header: 
"Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'lucieaverillphotography scripts' not found or invalid function name in /var/sites/l/lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525"

I don't know what this means, and it disappears when I remove the function from my functions.php, but now I am unable to use it at all.